# rsync ignores --chown/--usermap

Tags: debian, rsync

I'm running ansible with the `synchronize` module, which underneath runs rsync.
My problem is not ansible-related, as I took the rsync command from the debug output and ran it manually - still the same issue.

The command I ran is:

`/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --compress --delete-after --archive "/local/path" "ansible@1.2.3.4:/remote/path" --chown=myuser:myuser`

Whatever I try - I end up with the directory belonging to `root:root`.

I therefore now rsync successfully runs as root, so it should have all neccessary permissions. I also tried using `--usermap=*:myuser --groupmap=*:myuser` - nothing.

I added `--chmod=750` - not being applied.

In the debug output (`-vvvv`), I can see my parameters again, but that's it.

No warning, no error, but also no later mention of anything containing "user", "group", "chown" etc...
rsync is 3.1.1 on Debian 8.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo` wasn't the offender... it was partially me, and maybe it's also a bug/feature working differently than expected.

My ansible task added the source folder name to the destination path, which resulted in that path being created, and than the source folder being created inside that folder, effectively doubling the folder structure to `/destination/path/source/source/...`

`--chmod` is being applied to the second `source` folder, but not to the one created as part of the destination structure. Therefore, the top `source` belongs to root, but the second `source` belongs to the user it should belong too.

Fixed my ansible task to use the proper path, and therefore also this issue.

I wonder if one should expect `rsync` to also `chown`/`chmod` folders that it creates as part of the destination path?

Answer (score 2):

The `chown` system call (and, by extension, the `chown` and `rsync --chown` commands) may only be used by `root`. You're connecting to the remote system as the `ansible` user, so the remote system will not permit the operation. The `rsync` command recognizes that it's not running as `root` on the remote system, so it silently ignores the `--chown` option and others like it (e.g., `--mapuser`).

The [rsync manual](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html) is not really explicit about this behavior, but if you specify the `--super` option as well, it will cause `rsync` on the remote system to assume it is running as `root`, even if it is not. This will allow it to attempt the `chown` operation, and to produce an error if or when it fails.

EDIT:

If you do manage to execute `rsync` on the remote system as `root` (e.g., using `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"`), you will still need to add a couple options for `--chown` to be usable. The manual states:

```
--chown=USER:GROUP
    This option forces all files to be owned by USER with group GROUP.
    This is a simpler interface than using --usermap and --groupmap
    directly, but it is implemented using those options internally, so
    you cannot mix them.
```

And here's what the manual says for `--usermap` and `--groupmap`:

```
--usermap=STRING, --groupmap=STRING
    ...
    For the --usermap option to have any effect, the -o (--owner)
    option must be used (or implied), and the receiver will need to
    be running as a super-user (see also the --fake-super option).
    For the --groupmap option to have any effect, the -g (--groups)
    option must be used (or implied), and the receiver will need to
    have permissions to set that group.
```

In addition to using `--rsync-path` to run it under `sudo`, try adding the `-o` and `-g` options as well.

Comment: I read something like that too, but... via `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"`, it actually runs as root, as I can see because the files are afterwards owned by root. Also, adding `--super` doesn't change anything - I tried that before.

Comment: Your question doesn't make it clear that your invocation of `rsync` causes it to run as root on the remote system. That being the case, you probably need the `-o` and `-g` options as well; I've updated my answer to explain why.

Comment: Yeah, it's only implicitely mentioned by the directory ending up belonging to root:root. I added the `--rsync-path` to the question, I removed it by error.

I tried adding `-o` and `-g`, and also `-p` (although they should be included in `--archive`) - didn't help.

Comment: My mistake, I missed that you had `--archive` specified. Perhaps the invocation under `sudo` is losing some options. Does the sudo log (not sure where it goes in Debian) show the correct options being applied?

Comment: `sudo` wasn't the offender... it was partially me, and maybe it's also a bug.